# How to transform Flink Source [ Data Stream ] String value to Map?

Tags: json, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-stream

Trying to convert Apache Flink Source String to Map using **scala**.

**My Source Streaming String** : key1=value1key2=2000-12-17 00:00:00key3=Testkey4=08.89198key5=103.000

Code :

```
val environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val out  = environment.addSource(...)
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
val texToMap = out.map(mapper.readValue(_,classOf[Map[Object,Object]])
println(textToJson)
```

Its throwing error like

org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: **Unrecognized token 'key1': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')**

Is there any way to transform the **String** value to **Map** since i'm new to flink implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Flink uses jackson shaded jar for some special uses. In your case, you need to import `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instead of Flink's shaded jackson dependency.
And at the same time, you need this because you're using Scala.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```